# Ansible Module Development: No module named ansible.runner?

Tags: python, module, ansible

I'm trying to write my first module in Ansible, which is essentially a wrapper around another module. Here is my module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ansible.runner
import sys

def main():
    module.exit_json(changed=False)

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
main()
```

and here is the error it gives me (stripped from 'msg'):

> ImportError: No module named ansible.runner

I am on ubuntu and installed ansible with aptitude, version is 1.9.1
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules have to essentially be standalone. The boilerplate gets injected at runtime (the text of the boilerplate replaces the import at the bottom), and the combined text of the module + boilerplate is squirted to the remote machine and run there. As such, you can't import things from ansible core like the runner (unless you install ansible on the remote machine- don't be that guy). "module" is one of the items that you have to create from stuff defined in the boilerplate. Here's a sample module skeleton I wrote:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import json

def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = dict(
            state     = dict(default='present', choices=['present', 'absent'])
        ),
        supports_check_mode = True
    )

    p = module.params

    changed = False

    state = p['state']

    if not module.check_mode:
        # do stuff
        pass

    #module.fail_json(msg='it broke')

    module.exit_json(changed=changed)

from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked a module I wrote a while back and I don't have such an import line. The only import I have is `from ansible.module_utils.basic import *`. The `module` object I create myself in `main`:

```
module = AnsibleModule(
    argument_spec=dict(
        paramA=dict(required=True),
        paramB=dict(required=False),
        paramC=dict(required=False),
    ),
    add_file_common_args=True,
    supports_check_mode=True
)
```